# Find two integer elements in array closest to each other in numerical difference - Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is actually a technical interview question I found.

Given an array, find the two integer elements that are closest to each other. Return the smallest pair if there are more than one [pair with the same difference between them].

I took a shot at this. As you can see, it looks ugly. I'm wondering about alternative, cleaner and more efficient approaches. I didn't do the last part of the question about returning the smallest pair if there are more than one but it works otherwise.

```
least_diff = 99999 #how to represent infinity?
ans_arr = []
for i in (0...arr.length)
    for k in (0...arr.length)
        if i != k 
            curr_diff = (arr[i] - arr[k]).abs
            if curr_diff < least_diff
                if ans_arr != nil
                    ans_arr.pop
                end
                least_diff = curr_diff
                ans_arr.push("\(#{arr[i]},#{arr[k]}\)")
            end
        end
    end
end

ans_arr[0]
```

Comment: Please give a better title to your question, describe the coding problem.

Comment: Might be more suitable for Code Review since you don't actually have a problem.

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to `arr.sort.each_cons(2).min_by { |a, b| b - a }`?

Comment: I've voted to close this question as *too broad*; it would actually be a good fit for [codereview.se]... the only thing that's keeping me from flagging for migration is that you haven't implemented the last part. Feel free to implement it, and put it up on CR for peer review. See you there!

Comment: "Return the smallest pair if there are more than" **what**?

Comment: Noted in the next paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

The nice thing about this problem being 1-dimensional is that the closest elements are guaranteed to be adjacent when the array is sorted. So I'd take this approach:

1. Sort the array.
2. Scan the array linearly, computing the difference between every adjacent element.
3. Record the minimum difference at every step — at the end of your list, this is the final answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [3, -43, 1, 98, 29, 8, 10, -66]

a.sort.each_cons(2).min_by{|x, y| y - x}
# => [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Ruby! But I can surely help out with the logic.

> For the answer of your question,
>
> **How to set *least_diff* infinity?**

-> If it is not infinite then also it will work but for that you have to find the maximum number you can store in *least_diff*, and assign that value to *least_diff*.

-> Also what if `if curr_diff < least_diff` is not true? you must have another part to check `if curr_diff == least_diff` & `else` part. (i.e. No condition is matched!)

> For answer of the second part of your problem,

-> You can check the smallest pair by checking the sum of the pair.

For example,

Suppose you have pairs, (5,6), (3,4) and (4,8) in your answer. Now according to problem, you have to find (3,4) from the above pairs.

(4+8=12) > (5+6=11) > (3+4=7), so least sum '7' is your answer.

So you can add in your code the following logic.

```
least_pair_sum = 9999 #Assign the maximum value as I mentioned above.
#in the if part
if curr_diff <= least_diff
      if ans_arr != nil
           curr_pair_sum = arr[i] + arr[k]  #Don't know the syntax! Just see the logic
           if curr_pair_sum <= least_pair_sum
                ans_arr.push("\(#{arr[i]},#{arr[k]}\)") 
           end
      end
      least_diff = curr_diff
      #Removed ans_arr.push("\(#{arr[i]},#{arr[k]}\)") so you have only answer in the array
end
```

Hope it can solve your problem.

Comment: *"you have to find the maximum number"* - finding the maximum difference is as hard as finding the minimum, i.e. you would have to write a similar algorithm that requires a variable `max_diff` initialized with the minimum.

Comment: *"You can check the smallest pair by checking the sum of the pair"* - the OP wants to find the smallest *difference*, not the smallest *sum*.

Comment: @Stefan My solution is to find _the smallest pair if there are more than one [pair with the same difference between them]_ as asked in the question!

Comment: I see, but your example pairs don't have the same difference.

Comment: @Stefan No, it has. (6-5=1) & (4-3=1) and we have to find (3,4) pair as answer, that what my logic does. (Pair (4,8) is used just for example.)

Comment: Sorry, I thought the code was just about finding the smallest pair in an array of pairs with the same difference.